# How to Unit Test a Symfony2 Bundle Extension::load()?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I can't find an adequate approach to this problem anywhere.
I have tried mocking the appkernel to get the configuration but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the `matthiasnoback/SymfonyDependencyInjectionTest` package: https://github.com/matthiasnoback/SymfonyDependencyInjectionTest#testing-a-container-extension